# How to open COM port using USB to RS232 converter?

Tags: c, port, usbserial

So I have USB port and converter cable on one side, and RS232 cable on other side. 
I am trying to open COM port using CreateFile() API, and so far I managed to do this:

```
HANDLE dev = CreateFile(devicePath, (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE), 0,  NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    ShowError("connectCOM()");
    if (dev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

But I get **AccessDenied** error. I am now stuck because I am new to C programming and device communication.

What is the necessary step before calling CreateFile API in case of virtual COM port?

Comment: What is the value of your `devicePath`?

Comment: How do you know the USB com port is "COM1" and not "COM3", etc.?

Comment: I looked it up in device manager. I didn't figure it out how to detect it programatically. Maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The first way could be like this, assuming your Serial USB convertor creates `/dev/ttyUSB0`, it also involves system call to set up the port :

```
int usbdev;
char command[10]; 
char response[10];
system("stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parity -icanon min 1 time 1");
usbdev = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
write(usbdev, command, 2);
read(usbdev, response, 1);
close(usbdev);
```

Another way to implement it,

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions

int main()
{
    /* Open File Descriptor */
    int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NDELAY );

    /* Error Handling */
    if ( USB < 0 )
    {
        //cout << "Error " << errno << " opening " << "/dev/ttyUSB0" << ": " << strerror (errno) << endl;
        perror("USB ");
    }

    /* *** Configure Port *** */
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    /* Error Handling */
    if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 )
    {
        //cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        perror("tcgerattr ");
    }

    /* Set Baud Rate */
    cfsetospeed (&tty, B9600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, B9600);

    /* Setting other Port Stuff */
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;        // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;       // no flow control
    tty.c_lflag     =   0;          // no signaling chars, no echo, no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag     =   0;                  // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]      =   0;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]     =   5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines
    tty.c_iflag     &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);// turn off s/w flow ctrl
    tty.c_lflag     &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
    tty.c_oflag     &=  ~OPOST;              // make raw

    /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
    tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );

    if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0)
    {
        //cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << endl;
    }

    /* *** WRITE *** */

    unsigned char cmd[] = {'I', 'N', 'I', 'T', ' ', '\r', '\0'};
    //int n_written = write( USB, cmd, sizeof(cmd) -1 );

    /* Allocate memory for read buffer */
    char buf [256];
    memset (&buf, '\0', sizeof buf);

    /* *** READ *** */
    int n = read( USB, &buf , sizeof buf );

    /* Error Handling */
    if (n < 0)
    {
        //cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        perror("read error ");
    }

    /* Print what I read... */
    //cout << "Read: " << buf << endl;
    printf("%s",buf);;

    close(USB);
}
```

My USB serial converter is in my office, not with me at the moment, so I will able to check it tomorrow,

Comment: "assuming your Serial USB convertor creates `/dev/ttyUSB0`" This assumption is likely to be wrong, as the OP uses `CreateFile()`, which seems to be a part of Windows.

Comment: @glglgl oh, really? I did not marked that, I am not windows developer, would you suggest me to delete my answer?